# Would the advantage against dragon breath weapons granted by dragon scale mail apply to Chimera's dragon head breath attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

In D&D 5e [dragon scale mail](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-scale-mail) grants many buffs, one of them is advantage on saving throws against dragon breath weapons. Would this apply to the dragon head breath weapon from a [chimera](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chimera)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Dragon is a specific creature type.

From the *Monster Manual*, on [creature types](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#Type):

> A monster’s type speaks to its fundamental nature. Certain spells, magic items, class features, and other effects in the game interact in special ways with creatures of a particular type. For example, an arrow of dragon slaying deals extra damage not only to dragons but also other creatures of the dragon type, such as dragon turtles and wyverns.
>
> [...]
>
> **Dragons** are large reptilian creatures of ancient origin and tremendous power. True dragons, including the good metallic dragons and the evil chromatic dragons, are highly intelligent and have innate magic. Also in this category are creatures distantly related to true dragons, but less powerful, less intelligent, and less magical, such as wyverns and pseudodragons.

Since a [chimera](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/chimera) does not have the Dragon creature type, it is a Monstrosity, it's breath weapon doesn't count for [Dragon Scale Mail](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-scale-mail).

#### It wouldn't be unreasonable to rule otherwise.

Above is the RAW ruling, but it seems perfectly reasonable for a DM to rule that the Dragon Scale Mail gives advantage against the chimera's dragon head breath weapon. It fits thematically, for sure, and the only difference in the chimera's and the red dragon's breath weapons is the word "head":

> **Chimera**
>
> ***Fire Breath (Recharge 5–6)***. The dragon head exhales fire in a 15­-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw, taking 31 (7d8) fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.
>
> **Adult Red Dragon**
>
> ***Fire Breath (Recharge 5–6)***. The dragon exhales fire in a 60-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a DC 21 Dexterity saving throw, taking 63 (18d6) fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

Comment: It seems fairly reasonable for a DM to allow it, even if RAW doesn't support it.

Comment: @ESCE Was adding that to the answer as you commented :P

Comment: Is there any set way to tell if a word is referring specifically to a creature type? Roll20 has the words capitalized on both the Chimera's breath weapon and the Dragon Scale Armor; I lack the books so I can't check it. Makes me wonder if there is a difference between uppercase "Dragon" and lowercase "dragon".

Comment: There is an example that maybe can give further support to your answer: the [Dragon Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/dragon-slayer) specifies that the bonuses apply to any dragon--type creature, not only dragons.

Comment: @ESCE As far as I've noticed, it's not a consistent difference; most of the times it is not capitalized, however. (check the cleric's Turn Undead, or the ranger's Favored Enemy).